# Eclipse Errors: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, eclipse

**This is my code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message";
        </EditText>
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send";
       </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

There's an error
at the first EditText and first Button lines, the first error being the one in the title, and the second one being:
'Element type 'EditText' must be followed by either Attribute Specifications, '>' or '/>'

What's wrong? the whole code is made (almost) exactly as shown here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

(and i'm sorry if I misspelled or forgot anything, I'm a noob here...)

EDIT: Thanks, guys, but I tried pasting your code over mine. Though there are no X signs, the debug tool still says there are some errors...

EDIT: Yes, I have the needed strings, as I followed the tutorial. But I don't understand... If I paste the code given on the tutorial's site to Eclipse, there's still an error! I'll try opening the .xml in another program.

Comment: Errors can also come from android:text if you don't have the corresponding strings. I edited my answer.

Comment: Try opening the file with the regular XML Editor and see if it tells you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close your tags either with `/>` in `<EditText key="value" />` or with `>`in `<EditText key="value"></EditText>`. Don't use `;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:** After that, if you still have errors, remove:

> android:hint="@string/edit_message"

and

> android:text="@string/button_send"

unless you have corresponding entries inside your values/strings.xml file for them:

```
<string name="edit_message">Enter a text</string>
<string name="button_send">Button text</string>
```

Comment: Sorry but this layout is a well formed XML. Copy/paste, you'll see

Comment: I did that once, tried it again now and it worked :D YAY! Thank you very much! (you'll be hearing from me again on this site, as I usually have problems with programming :P )

Comment: In case it has not been understood, the exchange between someone755 and Michel-F. Portzert implies a useful tip: if all seems correct and the error persists, highlight and cut the offending parts of the xml page, save and then copy them back in. (Absurd, I know, but it worked for me ...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it should look (notice ending "<" symbols and absence of ";")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           

android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"  
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
</EditText>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
</Button> 
</LinearLayout>
```